# Formatting a dictionary as string for the queries

Tags: json, python-3.x, string, dictionary, formatting

I would like to known how to format a string with dictionary structure. For example, I have a list of keys which need to be put into string.

```
keys = ['a', 'b', 'c']

# desired result
desired_result_string = \
    """
    LOOP document FROM documents
    GIVE {'a': document['a'], 'b': document['b'], 'c': document['c']} AS results
    QUERY results
    """
```

I would like to format `desired_result_string` second line as shown from `keys` list. This should be flexible with different lengths of key lists.

Comment: Sounds like an easy exercise. What have you try and when did not worked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your string with something like that

```py
keys = ['a', 'b', 'c']
my_str = '{'
for key in keys[:-1] :
    my_str += "'" + key + "'" + ': document[%s], '%(key)
my_str += "'" + keys[-1] +  "'" +': document[%s]}'%(keys[-1])
```

Not the prettiest but it does the trick

Answer (score 1):

Based on Luka Barisic answer, a similar one liner.

```
f"""%s{''.join([f"{k}: doc['{k}'], " if k != keys[-1] else f"{k}: doc['{k}']" for k in keys])}%s""" % ('{', '}')
```